# Перестала запускаться Виртуаульная машина VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox

Сегодня на ровном месте (буквально с утра запускалась) перестала запускаться виртуальная машина c Windows 10. При попытке запустить, выскакивает интерактивная консоль, вот скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что могло случиться? Что можно попробовать сделать, чтобы запустить ее?

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался, помогло отключение "Включить EFI (только специальные OC)"